# Decode Base 64 Image to Bitmap Android

Tags: java, android, base64

I have this image in base64 from the server

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKcAAABACAIAAADwNfCBAAABc0lEQVR42u3awU7EIBRA0f7/T+ti\r\nYtNQeIWBplTOXZpo9B1gaOP2o/XajIC6qIu6qIu6qIu6qIu6qIu6qIu6qIu6qIu6qFMXdVEXdVFP\r\nftxfE/2Fh3iPV9/HOsl8E2zw49WPA51huCVj8P9cvenr1HtH/PhkP79AdrtTH6M+4WR3dXv9AfWe\r\nEfdcvEvqyMeo15MHEz8Dd66bJvUFl8LD6smT1SiS8yERXOmpD1OvJK+8crfalE6OyV8wvEM9sLxU\r\nr18WwdXscqHEy2W2p823qmd3T/a8rXy2/mI7Vh4Msz1tvl69ybjmJVrP8Y78XvV93MFGz37iXq6D\r\nserxOUS97cH6fPPKLoLg9M6um9J3Nd024pWaRL1hu5ewE7PSi9LgI7yJpPL6tvJ7m204eelUr5xv\r\nP4MXcDeq33EhQj61+rR3YOorqusudeTUqa+njpy6FlBHvpy6fy9fTh35is/roi7qoi7qoi7qoi7q\r\noi7qoi7qyvYLRlwpio989F0AAAAASUVORK5CYA==
```

I am testing show the image in a bitmap,

```
byte [] byteArray = android.util.Base64.decode(input, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

but the bitmap always is null, any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have newline characters within your Base64 character sequence. Try to get rid of them. I'm talking about this: `\r\n`. Try this: (since I don't know how you formatted the string):

```
input = input.replace("\r\n", "").replace("\\r\\n", "");
```

Comment: Didn't work, i try it but without a nice result. Thanks for help.

Comment: However, keep this in mind. This is really a step closer to the solution. Do not remove this code.